# Substitution rule in complex analysis

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\lambda_{\mathbb{C}}$ be the Lebesgue measure in the complex plane. 
Let $f$ be an entire function and $g$ a continuous function.

I ask:

When does the substitution rule hold

$$\int_{\mathbb{C}} g(f(z)) f'(z) d\lambda_{\mathbb{C}}(z)=\int_{f(\mathbb{C})} g(w) d\lambda_{\mathbb{C}}(w)?$$

I suppose that $f$ should be a diffeomorphism could be sufficient, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that should be sufficient. You don't use your $f$ anywhere.

Comment: @Berci thank you, sorry for the typo

Comment: Is $f'(z)$ the complex derivative?

Comment: yes, precisely....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is hardly ever correct. For example, let $f(z) = iz,$ $g(z) = e^{-|z|}.$ Then the left side equals

$$i\int_{\mathbb C} e^{-|z|} \, d\lambda(z),$$

the right side equals

$$\int_{\mathbb C} e^{-|w|} \, d\lambda(w).$$

Note two things: i) The only entire diffeomorphisms of $\mathbb C$ into $\mathbb C$ are of the form $f(z) = az+b.$ ii) If $f$ is a holomorphic injective map from $U$ onto $V,$ then the correct change of variables is

$$ \int_{U} g(f(z))|f'(z)|^2 \, d\lambda(z) = \int_{V} g(w) \, d\lambda(w).$$

Just compute the real Jacobian of the map $z\to f(z)$ to see this.